# node-fetch -- typeof import("[...]/node-fetch/index")' has no call signatures

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-fetch

Copied from here: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#json ... my code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function doFetch() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github');
    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);
}

doFetch()
```

Error message -- referring to the `fetch('https://...)` call:

```
This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof import("[...]/node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index")' has no call signatures.
```

I've searched this and other sites, and this error seems pretty common with many modules, although I can only find fixes for examples using `import` instead of `require`.  I'm guessing it's pretty simple, but I just can't figure out how to fix this with require syntax.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

---

*If it matters: JavaScript (not TypeScript). node.js. VSCode on Mac. The error message is generated by the `dbaeumer.vscode-eslint` plugin.*

---

Answer (score 1):

actual documentation says:

> node-fetch from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require()

(even the place where copied from uses `import` now)

so you should use the `import` way:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

if you really insist on the `require` way, use this hack:

```js
const {default: fetch} = require('node-fetch');
```